# Extract Huffman Table Content From a JPEG Image

Tags: compression, jpeg, huffman-code

I'm new to JPEG / image compression. Basically I want to view / extract the content(bytes) of Huffman Table embedded inside a JPEG file.

Comment: Asking for links and documentation is usually off-topic for SO. Is there anything in particular in the JPEG article from Wikipedia you don't understand, you should clarify that. If you just want to see the contents of the DHT tables, try a hex editor/viewer.

Comment: Edited the question. I wanna know the process of extracting Huffman Tables.

Comment: This link has a good explanation: http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-huffman-coding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps.

1. You have to read the data from a DHT market. The structure is defined in the JPEG standard.

That gives you an array of counts--the number of codes of a given length.

2. You have to convert the counts to huffman codes.

The JPEG standard explains that process.